# Optimal way to implement Navigation Drawer in Android app

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

There are two ways of implementing the Navigation Drawer in the Android app

1) Create a single activity that sets the DrawerLayout as the content view and then have multiple fragments get swapped in and out of the same activity

2) Declare and define the Navigation Drawer in the BaseActivity and then have all activities inherit from the BaseActivity.

Are there performance considerations in these implementations?

Comment: Is your problem solved or do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 0):

No performance considerations for you to worry about. Implementation-wise it makes basically no difference, **2)** would just be more convenient if you had multiple `Activities` with a `NavigationDrawer`. What you are describing are just two different use cases for a `NavigationDrawer`.

---

### Regarding your questions

As I said you are just describing two different use cases for a `NavigationDrawer`:

> 1) Create a single activity that sets the DrawerLayout as the content
>   view and then have multiple fragments get swapped in and out of the
>   same activity

This would be an app where you have one `MainActivity` with a `NavigationDrawer` which is used to switch between the some content. The detail views in this case would not have a `NavigationDrawer`.

> 2) Declare and define the Navigation Drawer in the BaseActivity and
>   then have all activities inherit from the BaseActivity.

This describes an  app which would have the `NavigationDrawer` to quickly switch between content from any level. You can just open the `NavigationDrawer` in a detail view and go directly to a different part of the app.

In the end whether you implement **1)** or **2)** really is just a matter of personal preference and convenience and most importantly how you want your app to work.

---

One thing I can add is that it is rather uncommon to have a `NavigationDrawer` at every level in your app. `NavigationDrawers` are supposed to be top level menus so the user can easily navigate between different parts of the app that have nothing inherently to do with each other. Once you are in a specific part of your app it is best practice to simply use drill-down navigation.